# How to encrypt a Keras model?

Tags: encryption, keras, hdf5

Preparing to deploy a Keras model as part of a client-side product, I am trying to encrypt it so it's (more) protected.

This seems to be particularly difficult as:

1. Keras models are not pickalable
2. The native hdf5 (used by Keras) does not support encryption
3. hdf5 does not seem to be trivially read/written to/from a memory buffer

The only positive point at the moment is that the architecture can be serialized to JSON (`model.to_json()`) and encrypted, but I'm still stuck with encrypting the weights...?

Two notes:

1. I would much prefer a solution that does not need temporary files on disk
2. I'm trying to get this working for a windows client

Comment: If you expect to use it, it'll need to be decrypted anyway. Why do you want to encrypt it? To send over the network?

Comment: That's true. I am only using it locally on the client. But if I only decrypt it into memory at run-time, and have the evaluation code only as compiled binary, It will require a significantly harder hacking effort to get hold of and use.

Comment: @Bambi did you find a way to do this? You can answer your own question if you did